# How to programmatically set my UIButton image to 'redraw'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am using some vector graphics (.png) for my app. In photoshop, I can zoom in and always see a perfectly crisp boundary for simple geometric shapes, like circles. However, on my iPhone, my same graphics look jaggedy and rough. I found that if I change the image fill type to redraw', this helps the problem.

So, can someone please confirm if using redraw is the correct solution in this situation? Also, how can I make the image for a programmatically defined button use 'redraw' instead of the default (which I think is 'fill')?

Here is my current button's code:

```
UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn1 setTitle:@"Cool title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(7, 7, 150, 160)];
[btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myGraphic.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectFav) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_scroller addSubview:btn1];
```

Comment: "I found that if I change the image fill type to redraw, this helps the problem ... instead of the default which I think is fill" Can you clarify your point here? I've never heard of redraw vs fill "fill types".

Comment: But in answer to the question (a) `png` files are bitmaps, not vector graphics; (b) resizing them can be problematic (using a contentMode of aspect fill can mitigate the problems); (c) you generally should have screen resolution assets so no scaling is necessary as this offers the best UI, the best performance, and the most efficient use of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove this line:

```
 UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

add this line:

```
 UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

set content mode:

```
 [btn1 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeRedraw];
```

Hope this answers all your concerns!